# Bitbucket Pipeline Tags Trigger Not Working

Tags: tags, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, git-tag

I've been trying to get this pipeline to trigger with all sorts of different formats and this appears to be the correct one, but I must be missing something because it's still not working.

I'm just doing `yarn version --prerelease` to git tag and keep parity with the apps `package.json` version.

```
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
 tags:
  'v*-*':
     - step:
         script:
         - echo "I FEEL LIKE I'M TAKING CRAZY PILLS"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had assumed that my tags were being pushed to bitbucket with everything else when I did `git push` (it works that way in GH Actions). I had to explicitly push tags with `git push --tags` and then it started working.